# BeanProcessor partially works

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee

I am trying to populate my class using BeanProcessor, but it partially works.
My classes are as following

Addres class

```
public class Address {

    ..All attributes of address class go here...
        .. All setter and getters go here...
}
```

Employee class that has the address class as its member

```
public class Employee {

    private int ID;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String mobile;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String position;
    private String title;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String question;
        private String answer;
        private Address address;          << address class is a member of employee class
        .. All setter and getters go here....
}
```

My Model is as following:

```
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        try {

            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee,address "
                    + "WHERE employee.username = ? AND "
                    + "employee.AddID = address.ID");

            ps.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery();
            if (r.next()) {
                BeanProcessor bp = new BeanProcessor();
                emp = bp.toBean(r,Employee.class);
                System.out.println("name:" + emp.getName()); << shows the name correctly
                System.out.println("block:"+emp.getAddress().getBlock());<< the output is null
            }

            con.close();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }
       return emp;
    }
```

When I run the application it shows the emp object is correctly populated but the Address object inside it not, and it returns null for the getBlock() method, I checked the database block has a value. According to spiritwalker's answer blew, because it is not throwing nullpointer exception the conversion is done correclty, if thats wrong, whats your suggestion as an alternative to BeanProcessor?

Comment: NPE is a fair question. Could you check what happens when you call `(new Employee()).getAddress().getBlock();` ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [BeanProcessor documentation](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/BeanProcessor.html#toBean%28java.sql.ResultSet,%20java.lang.Class%29):

> Convert a ResultSet row into a JavaBean. This implementation uses reflection and BeanInfo classes to match column names to bean property names. Properties are matched to columns based on several factors:
>
> 1. The class has a writable property with the same name as a column. The name comparison is case insensitive.
> 2. The column type can be converted to the property's set method
>    parameter type with a ResultSet.get* method. If the conversion fails
>    (ie. the property was an int and the column was a Timestamp) an
>    SQLException is thrown.

Pay attention to the second point. ResultSet doesn't support `Address` class. So, BeanProcessor can't process fields of this type.

**UPDATE:** About SQLException during processing.

You should check your sql query. If it doesn't return column named `address` then BeanProcessor just doesn't touch this property and, thus, doesn't throw any exceptions.

**UPDATE:** About NullPointerException.

Yes it sounds weird that `getAddress().getBlock()` doesn't throw NullPointerException. But from documentation above it's clear that BeanProcessor can't properly initialize address field. My guess is that `getAddress()` somehow returns non-null object even without `setAddress` call. Please, double check Employee's default constructor and `getAddress` method.

You can also call `new Employee().getAddress().getBlock()` to check this up.

**UPDATE:** How to implement nested objects processing

I don't have an experience with BeanProcessor, but it offers some protected methods you could use. For example you can try to override [processColumn](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/BeanProcessor.html#processColumn%28java.sql.ResultSet,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29):

```
public class CustomBeanProcessor extends BeanProcessor {

    @Override
    protected  int[] mapColumnsToProperties(ResultSetMetaData rsmd, PropertyDescriptor[] props) throws SQLException {
          int[] mapping = super.mapColumnsToProperties(rsmd, props);
          for(PropertyDescriptor prop : props) {
                //find address property
                //change PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND value to index of column (addressid maybe)
          }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object processColumn(ResultSet rs, int index, Class<?> propType) throws SQLException {
        if(propType==Address.class) {
            //here you create address object
            //you may need several calls to rs.get to check for all address properties.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a much broader question. BeanProcessor can process only standard types and, thus, doesn't support nested beans. So, you could try to enhance your query and/or beans to read only standard types, using non-nested plain beans (block name directly in employee class, for example). You can also try to process addresses and employees separately and then link them together somehow. Google query bring me to the [discussion of similar topic](http://apache-commons.680414.n4.nabble.com/Commons-Dbutils-Request-feedback-for-possible-patch-handling-nested-beans-td734323.html)

Comment: I would like to recommend you to look on [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) instead of implementing your own ORM framework.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure the corresponding address record does have data in **block** column? It makes think this way because, you said **the output is null** rather than a **NullPointerException** which means the address is properly mapped and initialized by BeanProcessor, otherwise the emp.getAddress() should give you a Null and then emp.getAddress().getBlock() will end up with NPE?

And also, according to BeanProcessor JAVA doc ** If the conversion fails (ie. the property was an int and the column was a Timestamp) an SQLException is throw**, it does not look like there is anything wrong with converting.